# Sql server full text search performance with additional conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, full-text-search

We have a performance problem with SQL Server (2008 R2) Full text search. When we have additional where conditions to full-text search condition, it gets too slow.

Here is my simplified query:

```
SELECT * FROM Calls C
WHERE (C.CallTime BETWEEN '2013-08-01 00:00:00' AND '2013-08-07 00:00:00')
AND CONTAINS(CustomerText, '("efendim")')
```

Calls table's primary key is CallId (int, clustered index) and also Calls table indexed by CallTime. We have 16.000.000 rows and CustomerText is about 10KB for each row.

When I see execution plan, first it finds full-text search resultset and then joins with Calls table by CallId. Because of that, if first resultset has more rows, query gets slower (over a minute).

This is the execution plan:

[image: This is the execution plan]

When I run where conditions seperately, it returns 360.000 rows for CallTime condition:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Calls C
WHERE (C.CallTime BETWEEN '2013-08-01 00:00:00' AND '2013-08-07 00:00:00')
```

and 1.200.000 rows for Contains condition:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Calls C
WHERE CONTAINS(AgentText, '("efendim")')
```

So, what can I do to increase performans of my query?

Comment: I'd start by not using `BETWEEN`, its horrible for performance and readability.  I would instead use `(C.CallTime >= '2013-08-01 00:00:00' AND C.CallTime < '2013-08-07 00:00:00')`

Comment: It would be helpful if you'd post the table definition along with any indexes you've created.

Answer (score 0):

If you have indexed and sorted `Calls` according to their call time, Instead of calling:

```
WHERE (C.CallTime BETWEEN '2013-08-01 00:00:00' AND '2013-08-07 00:00:00')
```

You can find the first index with call time bigger than `'2013-08-01 00:00:00'` and the last index smaller than the `'2013-08-07 00:00:00'`

and your new conditional will be:

```
WHERE (C.CallTime BETWEEN first_index AND last_index)
```

which is faster than comparing dates.